# Setting a monitoring display with 4 monitors automaticaly

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, monitoring, 23.04

Good evening.

I'm trying to create a monitoring display on Ubuntu 23.04 Gnome interface using 4 (2x2) monitors. The idea is to when the machine is powered on, each terminal, browser and software is to be open on a different display automatically.
The problem I'm facing occurs when trying to open said apps using script or software, either it does not open or open all in the same display.

I already tried different solutions like devilspie, configcompiz, --geometry, display:x.x but nothing works or simply looks incompatible with the current scenario and searching the internet only returned responses over a decade old using Ubuntu 12/13.

I would like to know if someone already did something similar and how it was done since I fell this should not be a difficulty problem to solve, and I'm letting something amiss.

- Ubuntu 23.04 (Gnome interface)
- Nvidia P6000, 4 DisplayPort (Temporary)
- Monitor Config: 4 display, 2x2 (Following config.)

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+1920+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
XWAYLAND3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Comment: consider using a tiling window manager rather than a DE if this is all you will be doing with this computer. Otherwise, you can switch to x.org and use something like this: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=353706 . Wayland, which you are using now, won't let you do this

Comment: Good evening Esther. I made a little research about tiling window manage and was able to find some good options for this situation. I'm currently running some tests using [Tactile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4548/tactile/) and seems promising.
Thank you again, and if you want, mark your comment as an answer and I will set as the solution.

Comment: Did you try to `xrandr --output upper_left_display --primary`, run upper_left_app, `xrandr --output upper_right_display --primary`, run upper_right_app and so on…? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75121699/4970442) using `gdbus` might also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wayland, which Ubuntu Desktop uses by default in 23.04, does not allow you to manipulate which monitor to start a program on. Even if you switch to x.org, not all programs will respond/behave when asked to start on a specific monitor. There are some hacky tricks for misbehaving programs, such as using `wmctl` to move app windows to a specific monitor once they start, which you can set up using x.org if needed.

However, if this is all the computer is being used for, you can consider looking into tiling window managers, which should be much easier to set up to work like this.